# APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file

Tags: android, c++, c, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to running NDK samples, it is giving error as below , Any body knows what this error stand for, and where the APP_BUILD_SCRIPT environmental variable can be change ? Please some one help me on this ?

Clean-only build of configuration Default for project HelloJni **

C:\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd clean 
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9/jni/Android.mk
C:/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9/build/core/add-application.mk:176: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

Build Finished **

Comment: It tells you the problem, doesn't it?

Comment: @Camille your guess fixed problem i'm very thankful to you. i spent lot of time to trace out this, actually i had one more copy of android ndk (v r5.0) in drive.after i deleted, every thing going fine.

Comment: @Camille, i need to know which is the best open source project in android for facial features detection, i have requirement that i need to set frame over eyes, lips, checks. can you please suggest me for any open source

Comment: @user1929311 Seems like there is already some questions about it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526964/face-recognition-using-android-sdk-not-opencv/15542557#15542557 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269891/android-face-detection I hope you will find topic and questions interesting for you

Comment: @Camille, i found open CV library for face detection , about 60-70% of android app using openCV for all sort of image processing things, i imported sample projects from open cv SDK and i tried running the an app called opencv-facedetector , but i getting error Cannot run program "C:\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build": Launching failed
Error: Program "C:/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9/ndk-build" is not found in PATH