# Detecting faces for an Android App?

Tags: java, android, face-recognition

I'm want to create a basic app that can detect faces. What SDK method or Opensource options could I use for this if someone can help me with detecting faces I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Susan this is a basic example using **[FaceDetector.Face](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html)** Class:

```
public class FaceDetection  extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new myView(this));
    }

    private class myView extends View {

        private int imageWidth, imageHeight;
        private int numberOfFace = 5;
        private FaceDetector myFaceDetect;
        private FaceDetector.Face[] myFace;
        float myEyesDistance;
        int numberOfFaceDetected;

        Bitmap myBitmap;

        public myView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.jorgesys, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
            imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
            imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
            myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];
            myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                    numberOfFace);
            numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            Paint myPaint = new Paint();
            myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
                Face face = myFace[i];
                PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
                face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
                myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();

                canvas.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance * 2),
                        (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance * 2),
                        (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance * 2),
                        (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance * 2), myPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside your `/drawable` folder add a an image with several faces to test, this example use an image called **jorgesys.png**  (R.drawable.jorgesys)

more info:
**[Face recognition using android sdk not opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526964/face-recognition-using-android-sdk-not-opencv)**

Comment: For FaceDetection API, it seems to detect only the middle of the eyes and distance between them, but is it possible to get to individual eyes? Or is it possible to know that the face is slanted?