# Why detecting FaceDetector no faces?

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-detection

I am trying to detect faces from a Bitmap but it doesnt detect any faces.

```
...
    bm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
    Mat image=new Mat ( bm.getHeight(), bm.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8U, newScalar(4));
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bm, image);
    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    //Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
    mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(faceDetections.toArray()));
```

ps:CascadeClassifier.empty() returns false and bitmap is also not null

Thanks

Comment: check this sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492994/detecting-faces-for-an-android-app

Comment: Android Face-Detection Api doesnt work on my device(huawei) i have to implement it with OpenCV

Comment: is there nobody to solve and explain it ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the format to Bitmap.Config.RGB_565? That's the only one that works, apparently.